# XML values saved in a PHP array

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - How to parse this xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582592/php-how-to-parse-this-xml)
>   [Parse xml with php - storing parts into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655464/parse-xml-with-php-storing-parts-into-array)  (close to deletion or already deleted)

If I had the following XML file and I wanted to save the values in the tags `name` and `number` into an array called `department`, how would I be able to do it using PHP?

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <data>
    <record id="1">
      <department>
        <name>ACME</name>
        <number>5</number>
      </department>
      <floor>
        <name>ACME Floor</name>
        <number>5</number>
      </floor>
    </record>
  </data>
```

Comment: You could look at [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

DOMDocument::loadXML

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('book.xml');
    $books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
    foreach ($books as $book) {
        echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }

?>
```